# What triggers IE 9 Compatibility Button visibilty

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Does anyone know what triggers the compatibility button from being visible in IE 9?  I have two web pages that I believe are the same.  IE shows the compatibility on one page but not the other so something must be different which I am not seeing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found this as a default in IE9.  I unchecked it.

Alt >> Tools >> Compatibility View Settings >> Un-check "Display Intranet Sites in Compatibility View